# App access to your Facebook profile picture

Tags: android, ios, facebook, image, profile

I am developing an app that requires access to the users Facebook profile picture and with the blessing of the user potentially changing his/her picture to a new pic for a set time period before changing it back to the original pic. Can this be done if the user gives permission? Or is Facebook strictly against this type of action?

Comment: What did you find out when you did research on this topic?

Comment: hi. been searching for answers to this for last 3 days but come up with nothing. answers that I did get was not in line with the question at all, lets me think that facebook don't allow such access to apps?

Comment: Ok. It seems you are having difficulty asking a good question on StackOverflow. As you are a new user, I recommend you take a look at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially this page - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: yep. kind of new here. but thanks for the advise. will read up and get some pointers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't just access facebook and retrieve the profile pic. What you can do is integrate the facebook api into your app and work from there. Here is a link to that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ This is probably the only way you will be able to access the profile picture.

Comment: if you found this as the answer, please hit the checkmark and upvote thanks!